# Managing SQL Server connected to existing DotNetNuke website

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, dotnetnuke

Sorry if this question isn't "programmery" enough. Before my time at the company they paid for a very expensive website written in asp.net and dotnetnuke. Absolutely terrible but there's very little that can be done about that now. They won't give us access to the SQL Server for some bizarre reason but they've given us FTP access.

Is there some way I can install a database manager (like phpMyAdmin) using FTP? I think I've found the username and password but I'm not familiar with asp so it's quite a confusing system.

Help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

If know the connection string for the SQL Server you don't need to install anything on the server. MS SQL Server Management Studio (and many other database management tools) can open remote databases so you can run them on your own PC.
The fact that a DNN website runs from the SQL Server is not relevant.

Comment: Thanks Steve, I've been searching through all the files trying to find some db info but coming from a non ms background all this asp stuff is very confusing. I think I've found a username an a password, is there anything else I need to find?

Comment: I think I found the connection string. Is it: <add name="SiteSqlServer" connectionString="Data Source=dbserver;Initial Catalog=<removed>;User ID=<removed>;Password=<removed>" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" /> ? The problem is that as far as I can tell the sql server isn't on the same server as the website (or remote access is blocked)

Comment: The connection string is the correct place to get the login information.  It is very common for host providers to block access to the SQL server from outside of their network, and those do allow access from outside the network typically use a different server name for access from the internet than for access from inside their network.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the host credentials for the DotNetNuke website, you can log in and query the database through the built in SQL window in the DNN site. It doesn't give you much help (no browsing, no intellisense) but it does let you read and write to the database (assuming the application user has permissions - which typically it does or the DNN site doesn't really function all that well). This may be helpful depending on what you need to do (which wasn't really clear from your post).

Comment: I can login to the dnn site but afaik there isn't an sql window. I noticed in the admin panel that the sql module isn't enabled.

Comment: Do you have a Host menu and an Admin menu or just an Admin menu?